# Sonata Media Bundle with Sonata Admin Bundle 3.0 (or 2.4)

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to find a combination of sonata bundles to work with both Sonata Media Bundle and Sonata Admin Bundle 3.0 (or 2.4), but with no success.

The versioning on the official documentation is a total mess and does not help.

My actual composer contains:

```
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^2.3"
```

I'm on Symfony 2.8, but I'd love to be able to migrate to 3.x.

Did anyone find a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue, this is because Sonata Media didn't has yet 3.0 version, and the 2.4 version is incompatible with the new 3.0 version of Sonata Admin.
Some time ago was possible to install the unstable 2.4 version of Sonata Admin, but now, this version is not avaible because is replaced with the new 3.0 version.

The only thing that you can do is downgrade the Sonata Admin version to 2.3.1 that is the last version compatible with Sonata Media dependencies and wait until the 3.0 version of Sonata Media will be released.

I'm sorry for the bad news

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did, but Sonata Admin 2.3.1 has several problem with entity translations.

I'm following this [discussion](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3731) but things happen so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

you here can find [boilerplate with config.](https://github.com/enricotempesti/symfony-sonata-media-admin) A Boilerplate with Symfony 2.8 configured with Sonata Admin Bundle 2.3, User Bundle and Media Bundle with RTE support

Comment: Thank you Enrico, but as i commented on the previous answer Sonata Admin 2.3.1 has several problem with entity translations so I was looking for a solution based on Sonata 2.4 or above.